# How to make a request to post an array to the server?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I need to execute a request to send an array. But when I do this I get `null` as the result.

Result **Request Payload**:

```
[  
  {nom_name: "Test", cost: 500, quantity: 1, parentOrder_id: 19}, 
  {nom_name: "35634", cost: 100, quantity: 1, parentOrder_id: 19}
]
```

Result **Preview**:

```
{
  address: null
  apartment: null
  code: null
  cost: null
  date_delivery: null
  floor: null
  hierarchyLevel: 1
  is_new: true
  name: null
  nom_name: null
  order_id: 40
  parentOrder_id: null
  payment: null
  quantity: null
  telephone: null
}
```

How do I fix to prevent `null` values ​​from being sent to the server for the values ​​I am sending? And so that the post request sends exactly an array, and not a single object.

**service:**

```
create(order: Order[]): Observable<Order> {
    return this.http.post<Order>(`${env.url}/api/orders/create`, order);
}
```

**ts:**

```
  onSave() {
    const order: Order[] = 
    this.order.list.map(e => {
      const { order_id, ...rest } = e
      return ({ ...rest, parentOrder_id: 19 })
    })
    this._order.create(order)
      .subscribe(
        () => {
          console.log('Data Saved.')
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error)
        }
      );
  }
```

On the server I am using Nodejs and ORM Sequelize.

**node.js controller:**

```
module.exports.create =  function (req, res) {
    const order = db.orders.bulkCreate([
        {
            nom_name: req.body.nom_name,
            quantity: req.body.quantity,
            cost: req.body.cost,
            parentOrder_id: req.body.parentOrder_id
        }
    ])
    res.status(201).json(order);
};
```

Comment: If you log the data from `req.body` and before `res.status...`. It would be helpful.
Maybe the problem is on `balkCreate`

Comment: @StPaulis I doubt that the problem is in the controller, I tried to send data this way using `Rest Client` and everything worked.

Comment: @StPaulis But post request through the Angular client is not working.

Comment: If you are waiting an Array as a result, your service should be like this ```create(order: Order[]): Observable<Order[]> {
    return this.http.post<Orde[]r>(`${env.url}/api/orders/create`, order);
}```

Comment: @StPaulis I have already tried to do this, in the end the result is null for all values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't personally worked a lot with sequelize, but I'm pretty sure that you need to pass the the request-body object directly since `req.body` contains the array of data and thus `req.body.nom_name` for example will be `undefined`. Also `bulkCreate` is defined as an [async-function](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-bulkCreate) that you should await before sending the response:

```
module.exports.create = async (req, res) => {
    const orders = await db.orders.bulkCreate(req.body);
    res.status(201).json(orders);
};
```